# Extracting data from JSON and iterating using python

Tags: python, json, api, dictionary, hubspot

So I'm using the HubSpot API which tracks "deals" in the system, but fails to have a robust way to search/filter the data it returns. So it simply dumps ALL the "deals" out of the system into one big JSON and then gives you some pagination info to help you glue it back together on the back-end.

Here is a demo/source API URL:
https://api.hubapi.com/deals/v1/deal/all?hapikey=demo

This returns JSON which looks basically like this (shortened):

```
{  
   "deals":[  
      {  
         "portalId":62515,
         "dealId":17886969,
         "isDeleted":false,
         "associations":{
            "associatedCompanyIds":[  
               113448746
            ]
         },
         "properties":{
            "dealname":{  
               "value":"Google Website"
            },
            "amount":{  
               "value":"150000"
            },
            "hubspot_owner_id":{  
               "value":"72"
            },
            "dealstage":{  
               "value":"qualifiedtobuy"
            },
            "dealtype":{  
               "value":"existingbusiness"
            }
         },
         "imports":[  

         ]
      }
   ],
   "hasMore":false,
   "offset":28692358
}
```

but...

1) There are lots of deals returned, I'd like to filter this by `dealtype` which is a variable that can change. For instance, I'd like to return only deals that have the value "qualifiedtobuy"

2) I then need to run a query and "do stuff" with each deal, based on the `dealId`. I imagine this means I need to get all of the above into a `dict` and somehow and then iterate? I'm not sure.

So this is what I have so far, but this really just grabs the JSON and turns it into  `dict` (I think).

```
import requests
import json

apikey = "demo"
url = 'https://api.hubapi.com/deals/v1/deal/all?hapikey=' + apikey
response = requests.get(url)
response.raise_for_status()
jsonDeals = response.json()
dict_object = dict(jsonDeals)
```

I'm not sure what steps to take next to grab the `dealId` values and then "do stuff" with each of the values returned.

Any help is much appreciated.

UPDATE: here is the raw dict, not simplified for the PROPERTIES for ONE DEAL:

```
{u'hs_lastmodifieddate': {u'sourceId': None, u'timestamp': 1457479099306, u'versions': [{u'timestamp': 1457479099306, u'sourceVid': [], u'name': u'hs_lastmodifieddate', u'value': u'1457479099306', u'source': u'CALCULATED'}], u'value': u'1457479099306', u'source': u'CALCULATED'}, u'pipeline': {u'sourceId': None, u'timestamp': 1457479063182, u'versions': [{u'timestamp': 1457479063182, u'name': u'pipeline', u'value': u'default', u'sourceVid': []}], u'value': u'default', u'source': None}, u'num_associated_contacts': {u'sourceId': None, u'timestamp': 0, u'versions': [{u'source': u'CALCULATED', u'name': u'num_associated_contacts', u'value': u'0', u'sourceVid': []}], u'value': u'0', u'source': u'CALCULATED'}, u'dealstage': {u'sourceId': None, u'timestamp': 1457479063157, u'versions': [{u'timestamp': 1457479063157, u'sourceVid': [], u'name': u'dealstage', u'value': u'qualifiedtobuy', u'source': u'API'}], u'value': u'qualifiedtobuy', u'source': u'API'}, u'createdate': {u'sourceId': None, u'timestamp': 1457479063181, u'versions': [{u'timestamp': 1457479063181, u'name': u'createdate', u'value': u'1457479063181', u'sourceVid': []}], u'value': u'1457479063181', u'source': None}, u'hs_salesforceopportunityid': {u'sourceId': None, u'timestamp': 1457479097680, u'versions': [{u'timestamp': 1457479097680, u'sourceVid': [], u'name': u'hs_salesforceopportunityid', u'value': u'00628000007nhqFAAQ', u'source': u'SALESFORCE'}], u'value': u'00628000007nhqFAAQ', u'source': u'SALESFORCE'}, u'hubspot_owner_assigneddate': {u'sourceId': None, u'timestamp': 1457479097680, u'versions': [{u'timestamp': 1457479097680, u'sourceVid': [], u'name': u'hubspot_owner_assigneddate', u'value': u'1457479097680', u'source': u'SALESFORCE'}], u'value': u'1457479097680', u'source': u'SALESFORCE'}, u'hubspot_owner_id': {u'sourceId': None, u'timestamp': 1457479097680, u'versions': [{u'timestamp': 1457479097680, u'sourceVid': [], u'name': u'hubspot_owner_id', u'value': u'11626092', u'source': u'SALESFORCE'}], u'value': u'11626092', u'source': u'SALESFORCE'}, u'amount': {u'sourceId': None, u'timestamp': 1457479063157, u'versions': [{u'timestamp': 1457479063157, u'sourceVid': [], u'name': u'amount', u'value': u'150000', u'source': u'API'}], u'value': u'150000', u'source': u'API'}, u'hs_createdate': {u'sourceId': None, u'timestamp': 1457479063181, u'versions': [{u'timestamp': 1457479063181, u'name': u'hs_createdate', u'value': u'1457479063181', u'sourceVid': []}], u'value': u'1457479063181', u'source': None}, u'salesforcelastsynctime': {u'sourceId': None, u'timestamp': 1457479099298, u'versions': [{u'timestamp': 1457479099298, u'sourceVid': [], u'name': u'salesforcelastsynctime', u'value': u'1457479070904', u'source': u'SALESFORCE'}], u'value': u'1457479070904', u'source': u'SALESFORCE'}, u'closedate': {u'sourceId': None, u'timestamp': 1457479099298, u'versions': [{u'timestamp': 1457479099298, u'sourceVid': [], u'name': u'closedate', u'value': u'1461013200000', u'source': u'SALESFORCE'}], u'value': u'1461013200000', u'source': u'SALESFORCE'}, u'dealtype': {u'sourceId': None, u'timestamp': 1457479063157, u'versions': [{u'timestamp': 1457479063157, u'sourceVid': [], u'name': u'dealtype', u'value': u'existingbusiness', u'source': u'API'}], u'value': u'existingbusiness', u'source': u'API'}, u'dealname': {u'sourceId': None, u'timestamp': 1457479063157, u'versions': [{u'timestamp': 1457479063157, u'sourceVid': [], u'name': u'dealname', u'value': u'Google Website', u'source': u'API'}], u'value': u'Google Website', u'source': u'API'}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object returned by `response.json()` has already been converted to a `dict`, so you do not need to do anything further with it. To get a list of all the `qualifiedtobuy` deals, try something like this:

```
jsonDeals = response.json()

deals = []
for deal in jsonDeals['deals']:
    properties = deal['properties']
    if ('dealstage' in properties and
        properties['dealstage']['value'] == 'qualifiedtobuy'):
        deals.append(deal)

if deals:
    print(deals[0]['dealId'])
else:
    print('found no "qualifiedtobuy" deals')
```

Comment: here it doesn't like: `dealtype = deal['properties']['dealtype']['value']` - i get an error saying `KeyError: 'dealtype'`

Comment: this is the `dict` i get when i simply `print deal['properites']` for one deal: `{
 u'dealstage':
  {
   u'value': u'qualifiedtobuy'
  },
 u'hubspot_owner_id':
  {
   u'value': u'72'
  },
 u'amount':
  {
   u'value': u'150000'
  },
 u'dealtype':
  {
   u'value': u'existingbusiness'
  },
 u'dealname':
  {
   u'value': u'Google Website'
  }
}`

Comment: thanks for the quick response - now i get: `print(deals[0]['dealId'])
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @gotmike. My code was based on the json example in your question, and it works fine for that. However, it seems that not every deal has a 'dealtype', so I've added an extra check for that in my answer. Please also note that if there are no "qualifiedtobuy" deals, then obviously the list will be empty ;-)

Comment: @gotmike. Sorry, I just noticed it should be looking in `dealstage` for "qualifiedtobuy", not `dealtype`. I've amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: for some reason still not picking it up... i just added the raw `dict` values to my initial question/post. this is from putting `print properties` just after `properties = deal['properties']` - i just put one of them... maybe the path/order is wrong or something?

Comment: got it - should be: `if ('dealstage' in properties and properties['dealstage']['value'] == 'qualifiedtobuy'):` - just missing the `['value']` part.

Comment: @gotmike. Yes, sorry - that's what I get for trying to do things in a hurry and not test things properly. The code in my answer should now hopefully work .

Comment: yep - works great. now any quick way to get from dict back to json for output?

Comment: @gotmike. Something like `json.dumps(mydict)` will convert the `dict` to a string that can be written to disk.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
dict_object = json.loads(jsonDeals)
```

will give you your dictionary you don't want to just cast the string to a dict, as some json components differ from those in python such as lower case true vs python's True

to interact with the items, you need only index into the dict based on the keys

```
for deal in dict_object['deals']:
     print deal['dealId'], 'for instance'
```

can you confirm that `jsonDeals` is a json string ... if it is what you posted at the top of your question, it should work, i tested it out:

```
>>> a = """
... {  
...    "deals":[  
...       {  
...          "portalId":62515,
...          "dealId":17886969,
...          "isDeleted":false,
...          "associations":{
...             "associatedCompanyIds":[  
...                113448746
...             ]
...          },
...          "properties":{
...             "dealname":{  
...                "value":"Google Website"
...             },
...             "amount":{  
...                "value":"150000"
...             },
...             "hubspot_owner_id":{  
...                "value":"72"
...             },
...             "dealstage":{  
...                "value":"qualifiedtobuy"
...             },
...             "dealtype":{  
...                "value":"existingbusiness"
...             }
...          },
...          "imports":[  
... 
...          ]
...       }
...    ],
...    "hasMore":false,
...    "offset":28692358
... }"""
>>> import json
>>> d = json.loads(a)
>>>
```

Comment: thanks! i'm getting an error trying this, however, `dict_object = json.loads(jsonDeals)` - `TypeError: expected string or buffer` perhaps i need to use something other than `response.json()`?

Answer (score 0):

`Python` is certainly an easy way and more readable. Sometimes I get lazy, so I just use `jq` (Doc : https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

For your example, it can be a one-liner in `Bash`:

```
curl -s https://api.hubapi.com/deals/v1/deal/all?hapikey=demo | \
    jq '.deals[] | select(.properties.dealstage.value=="qualifiedtobuy")'
```

This will give you the one line you need in nice format. Adding a `--compact-output` flag to `jq` will print each of the object in one line. Then you can redirect the output to a file if you need more complicated manipulation.

In the case of your test url, with the flag it outputs only one record:

```
{"portalId":62515,"dealId":17886969,"isDeleted":false,"associations":{"associatedVids":[],"associatedCompanyIds":[113448746],"associatedDealIds":[]},"proper
ties":{"pipeline":{"value":"default","timestamp":1456622756943,"source":null,"sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"pipeline","value":"default","timestamp":14
56622756943,"sourceVid":[]}]},"dealname":{"value":"Google Website","timestamp":1456622756908,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"dealname","
value":"Google Website","timestamp":1456622756908,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"amount":{"value":"150000","timestamp":1456622756908,"source":"API","sour
ceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"amount","value":"150000","timestamp":1456622756908,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"closedate":{"value":"1461042000000","ti
mestamp":1456622756908,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"closedate","value":"1461042000000","timestamp":1456622756908,"source":"API","sour
ceVid":[]}]},"hubspot_owner_id":{"value":"72","timestamp":1456622756908,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"hubspot_owner_id","value":"72","
timestamp":1456622756908,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"hs_lastmodifieddate":{"value":"1456622756943","timestamp":1456622756943,"source":"CALCULATED","so
urceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"hs_lastmodifieddate","value":"1456622756943","timestamp":1456622756943,"source":"CALCULATED","sourceVid":[]}]},"hubspot_ow
ner_assigneddate":{"value":"1456622756908","timestamp":1456622756908,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"hubspot_owner_assigneddate","value"
:"1456622756908","timestamp":1456622756908,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]},"num_associated_contacts":{"value":"0","timestamp":0,"source":"CALCULATED","sour
ceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"num_associated_contacts","value":"0","source":"CALCULATED","sourceVid":[]}]},"dealstage":{"value":"qualifiedtobuy","timestam
p":1456622756908,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"dealstage","value":"qualifiedtobuy","timestamp":1456622756908,"source":"API","sourceVid
":[]}]},"hs_createdate":{"value":"1456622756943","timestamp":1456622756943,"source":null,"sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"hs_createdate","value":"145662
2756943","timestamp":1456622756943,"sourceVid":[]}]},"createdate":{"value":"1456622756943","timestamp":1456622756943,"source":null,"sourceId":null,"versions
":[{"name":"createdate","value":"1456622756943","timestamp":1456622756943,"sourceVid":[]}]},"dealtype":{"value":"existingbusiness","timestamp":1456622756908
,"source":"API","sourceId":null,"versions":[{"name":"dealtype","value":"existingbusiness","timestamp":1456622756908,"source":"API","sourceVid":[]}]}},"impor
ts":[]}
```

For simple extraction of fields, you can do something like this:

```
curl -s https://api.hubapi.com/deals/v1/deal/all?hapikey=demo | \
    jq --compact-output --raw-output \
    '.deals[] | select(.properties.dealstage.value=="qualifiedtobuy") | [.properties.amount.value, .properties.closedate.value, .properties.createdate.value, .properties.dealname.value] | @csv'
```

This will give lines matched, each line containing deal amount, close date, create date, and deal name, comma-separated of course. `--raw-output` flag takes away the escaping of quotes to make the output cleaner. For your test url, it gives:

```
"150000","1461042000000","1456622756943","Google Website"
```

More matches, more lines. Redirect output and be done your day. Less dev time, better world.